# Modular inverse computation - avoiding Euclidean algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, lattices, computational-number-theory, integer-programming

Modular inverse is known to be computable by Extended Euclidean algorithm which is the reaping the rewards of computing the GCD of two numbers or proving two numbers are coprime.

> If we already know the numbers $a,q$ are coprime then do we know any better way to compute $a^{-1}\bmod q$ without Euclidean algorithm?

Essentially can we solve the integer program:

\begin{gather*}
\exists u,v\in\mathbb Z \\
-q/2<u<q/2 \\
-a/2<v<a/2 \\
au+qv=1
\end{gather*}

without LLL algorithm?

Why cannot we think differently than the Euclidean algorithm? Is there any barrier?

Implicit in the question is why cannot we NC reduce Extended GCD algorithm to GCD computation itself as we can replace last constraint by $$au+qv=g$$ where $g$ now is $\operatorname{GCD}(a,q)$ (now assumed may not be coprime)?

$NC$ stands for Nick's class. Essentially Euclidean algorithm is performed on $O(n)$ sequential steps where $n$ is number of bits in $a$ and $q$ on a single processor. Can we increase the number of processors to $poly(n)$ and reduce the number of steps to $O(poly(\log n))$? This question is captured by the class $NC$.

Comment: You could compute $a^{\phi(q)-1}$ via square-and-multiply. But this is probably not what you're looking for as computation of $\phi(q)$ could be nontrivial.

Comment: But  @Aeryk's suggestion could be useful in case $q$ is known to be prime.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the phrase "NC reduce".  Please edit that part of the question to avoid the abbreviation by spelling out what is meant there.

Comment: @KConrad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  wow, "Nick's Class" is such an unexpected answer, esp. since Nick is a first name.  Imagine we spoke of "Isaac's Method" instead of "Newton's Method".

Comment: @KConrad It does not stop there: Nick Pippenger returned the favour by naming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SC_(complexity) .

Comment: @KConrad well praising a family line for an individual's work!!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek that's amazing.

Comment: Pierre's Last Theorem, The Bernhard Hypothesis, Max's Lemma, Joseph numbers, ....

Comment: Complexity theory usually doesn't provide nontrivial "barriers" to fast algorithms; the well-known "barriers" are barriers to proving *lower bounds*. [As you know](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52308), modular inverse is not known to be in $\mathsf{NC}$, but there's really no "barrier" standing in the way of a better algorithm for it, other than our lack of imagination.

Comment: On google scholar, I found searching through the literature related to the paper "A parallel extended GCD algorithm" very intriguing.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I think there was earlier discussion somewhere on MO that the work or some related work by the same author is incorrect. Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122616/is-integer-gcd-in-nc. There is some discussion here too but not totally relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338053/why-does-division-parallelize-but-not-continued-fractions-and-is-there-an-analog.

Comment: @Turbo  If it is incorrect, perhaps those in the know should get the paper retracted.

Comment: @PaceNielsen ".. the work $or$ some related work..". I think wiki had a writing once that quoted the author's work which claimed GCD is in NC. This is discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122616/is-integer-gcd-in-nc.

Comment: @Turbo Oh, so the incorrectness you mentioned, as far as you know, is limited to an *unpublished* paper.  Then I stand by my comment, that using google scholar to look through the literature related to the *published* paper is a good idea.  (It would still be a good idea if the published paper were incorrect, as the literature around it would hopefully reveal that fact.)

Comment: By the way, you could contact the author, to get clarification on the situation.